# SwaggerUI missing contenType header in POST-request

Tags: post, content-type, swagger-ui, form-parameter

I'm using swaggerUI to verfy my swagger specification.

GET methods or a POST method with a body works fine, but i get problems when using a POST method with @FormParam. My server says it is missing a contenttype from the request and it is right, the generated command by SwaggerUi looks like this

```
curl -X POST "https://localhost:8184/authentication/password/reset?username=chrome&newPassword=11114444" -H "accept: application/json"
```

my swaggerUI code looks that way

```
 /user/delete:
post:
  tags:
  - "Usermanagement"
  summary: Löscht einen Nutzer
  description: Löscht einen Nutzer anhand seines "username"
  consumes: 
  - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  produces: 
  - application/json
  parameters: 
  - in: query
    name: username
    type: "string"
    description: Benutzername
  responses:
    200:
      description: Nutzer wurde erfolgreich gelöscht
    400:
      description: Der Löschvorgang konnte nicht ausgeführt werden
```

whereas my server code looks like that

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/activation")
public Response activation(@NotNull @FormParam("username") String username,
        @NotNull @FormParam("active") Boolean active) {
    return runWithExceptionMapper(() -> {
        if (active) {
            userService.activateUser(username);
        } else {
            userService.deactivateUser(username);
        }
    });
}
```

Server code is in general fine, it works from browser and from Postman.

I just can't figure out why swaggerUI doesn't send contenttype with the curl command or how I can force it to do so.

EDIT:
I figured out that the brwoser is not sending the curl-command, but a http-request. But there is still missing content in the payload, namly content-type. Why my server doen't know what to do with the "unknown" data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.

Mistake was the in-type of my parameters. Instead of query it should be formData (obviously).

Correct specification code looks like this

```
/user/delete:
post:
tags:
- "Usermanagement"
summary: Löscht einen Nutzer
description: Löscht einen Nutzer anhand seines "username"
consumes: 
- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
produces: 
- application/json
parameters: 
  - in: formData
  name: username
  type: "string"
  description: Benutzername
responses:
  200:
    description: Nutzer wurde erfolgreich gelöscht
  400:
    description: Der Löschvorgang konnte nicht ausgeführt werden
```